# Refresh and access token flow in JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I have developed a standard JWT system that logs in and issues an access token and a refresh token. The access token expires after a short amount of time and there is a route to refresh the token.

I use `axios` to make requests but I am not sure how to deal with expired tokens. For example, if I make a request to `/secret_route` with my access token and it's expired, do I need to wait for a `403` and then make a request to `/refresh_token` and then make the original request again? Seems messy from a programming point of view and quite wasteful on the network. Is there an efficient/elegant way to do this?

Comment: The expiry date is part of the jwt, so your client would know when it has expired and needs to be refreshed.

Comment: Wouldn't that be messy with timezones, etc?

Comment: @DaraJava `exp` is in unix epoch. As long as the JS runtime (host) has a correct timezone and time set - everything would be fine.

Comment: @DaraJava It's an UTC timestamp, timezones don't matter. And yes, if something didn't work out it's still a good idea to fall back to refresh-and-retry on a 403 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a solution that I feel is more robust than checking the timestamp. Thanks @Bergi but I am concerned about the system clock. I use axios interceptors to refresh the token on a 401

```js
  // Request interceptor for API calls
  axios.interceptors.request.use(
    async config => {
      config.headers = { 
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("accessToken")}`,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
      }
      return config;
    },
    error => {
      Promise.reject(error)
  });

  // Allow automatic updating of access token
  axios.interceptors.response.use(response => response, async (error) => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
      originalRequest._retry = true;
      const res = await axios.post('/users/token', { token: localStorage.getItem('refreshToken') });
      setToken(res.data.accessToken);

      return axios.request(originalRequest);
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Adapted from https://thedutchlab.com/blog/using-axios-interceptors-for-refreshing-your-api-token